# Is there any API in codepipeline that returns the message why pipeline got failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

**Usecase**

I want to extract the reason of why my codepipeline has been failed and send that information as an email. In the codepipeline console, i can see the below message under 'Latest action execution message` heading.

Is there any way i can able to extract this message using any Codepipeline API methods. Because i tested most the `AWS cli codepipeline` commands but didn't find this information.

Thanks
Any help is appreciated

[image: See the highlighted heading]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup an email notification using SNS, and then configure your pipeline to send alerts to the corresponding SNS topic.

You can read detailed steps in [Tutorial: Set Up a CloudWatch Events Rule to Receive Email Notifications for Pipeline State Changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-cloudwatch-sns-notifications.html).

Since the default notification doesn't include the job failure message, you'll need to write a Lambda Function that receives the state change event object and calls the [getPipelineState](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_GetPipelineState.html) function to return the last failure message.

Comment: Thanks @jweyrichs. I know that option. But I want the message that is displayed in the console. So that the person will know the reason as soon as he sees the email rather than going inside and checking

Comment: You can write a Lambda to do that for you. Configure your SNS topic to trigger a Lambda function that receives the CodePipeline status change object and format an e-mail as you wish.

Comment: Thats exactly what i am doing. Based on this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html codepipeline only send these events structures to the targets(i.e.Lambda,SNS). In that events structure there is no `message field`. Since the `error message` is showing in the console, my hunch is maybe aws uses some API method to retrieve this..

Comment: Right. I believe only [getPipelineState](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_GetPipelineState.html) can bring you that information. The event object your lambda receives upon state change also contains the pipeline name, so you can pass it to `getPipelineState` to retrieve the error message.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what i am looking for. Could you please put the above  `API` in your answer. So that i will accept it.

Comment: GetPipelineState can give you the wrong answer in some circumstances (see my answer). We recently released a new API that it's probably a better fit for what you're trying to do: ListActionExecutions.

Answer (score 3):

CodePipeline's CloudWatch events include a pipeline execution id, which you can use to call ListActionExecutions. ListActionExecutions will give you the status for failed actions and will be stable over time.

GetPipelineState has the status for the latest pipeline execution in a given stage. It's possible for a pipeline execution to enter a stage after a failure and before you receive a CloudWatch event (so you observe the wrong pipeline execution).

Comment: whenever i try this access the `ListActionExecutions` API it is throwing an error in both `aws cli` and `lambda`. In lambda the error is like this `codepipeline.listActionExecutions is not a function`.

Comment: For reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_ListActionExecutions.html (API). You may need a newer release of the SDK or CLI.